# I want to put a close button in app.xaml window content template in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have created custom template of target type window now i want that whenever i declare the template the button automatically arrives as a close button on top right corner to close the window but in code of app.xaml i am not getting any idea to perform form closing handler on button click.

```
  <Application x:Class="Application"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFCDFF"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="WindowState"  Value="Maximized"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window" x:Key="WindowTemplate">
        <AdornerDecorator>
            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Control x:Name="FocusCatcher"></Control>
                <TextBlock Text="Menu Section" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Content="X" FontFamily="Tahoma" Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Button>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
                <StatusBar Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="Current Editing Mode" />
                </StatusBar>
            </Grid>
        </AdornerDecorator>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

And In Mainwindow.xaml

```
  <Window x:Class="MainWindow" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Style="{StaticResource MyWindowStyle}" Template="{StaticResource WindowTemplate}">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

The Form Looks Somehow like this : [image: [1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I get you right you want on button click window to close?
then add some extra to your button xaml:

```
 <Button x:Name="someName" Content="X" FontFamily="Tahoma" Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="someName_Click"></Button>
```

and implement in the code

```
Private Sub someName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles someName.Click End Sub
```

to close it.

Comment: but it is to be kept in template of application.xaml